# List.Before method

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects (i.e., a `List`) and I'd like a **fluent** function that will give me the members of that list before a certain member (or the first occurrence thereof).

Here's what I'm using. Is there a cleaner or more concise way?

```
public static List<T> Before<T>(this List<T> Source, T Value)
{
    List<T> functionReturnValue = default(List<T>);
    functionReturnValue = new List<T>();
    foreach (T Thing in Source) {
        if (Thing.Equals(Value)) {
            break; 
        }
        functionReturnValue.Add(Thing);
    }
    return functionReturnValue;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm tempted to.  If you don't want to get down-voted, don't talk about getting downvoted.

Comment: And on another note, your attempt here is important, because it illustrates what you want to do.  If it wasn't there, fewer people would understand what you're asking for with this question.

Comment: How would you decide which solution is more "elegant" than another?

Comment: @mustaccio, I won't! I just wanted an answer like everyone else. As you can see the answer was clearly better than my attempt so I accepted it. Can you forgive me for being so bold as to encourage people to provide a good thoughtful answer? It wasnt' a demand, but a request. "Most elegant" isn't part of the question. Is that why it's on hold?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, "most elegant" is completely subjective and unattainable, but you could use `TakeWhile`:

```
public static List<T> Before<T>(this List<T> Source, T Value)
{
    return source.TakeWhile(i => !i.Equals(Value)).ToList();
}
```

Note that you  *could* make it more general by using `IEnumerable` instead of `List`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Before<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Source, T Value)
{
    return source.TakeWhile(i => !i.Equals(Value));
}
```

In fact the [doucmentation for `TakeWhile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804(v=vs.100).aspx) gives an example that basically does what you want, just with string comparisons.

Comment: Your second answer is probably in all likelihood irreducibly elegant. It can't get any simpler yet still get the job done. It's not unattainable; you just attained it. If we define elegant to mean the least number of mental constructs required to visually parse it (most easily understood).